# The Repositories for 10.04 will stop working in April 2012, But I can still Use 10.04?

Tags: 10.04, repository, lts

I just bought an emachines T5048 for $60.

Turns out newer kernels won't boot on this machine, no matter what options are used. (the PC is from late 2006, ATI Radon Xpress 200 chipset)

I know the ubuntu repositories for 10.04 will stop working. 
Come 12.04, How will I be installing software on this PC?
Any other gotchas?

Comment: Depending on how much time you want to spend on your problem, perhaps we can find a solution to why newer kernels will not boot. I do not know how interested you might be in building a custom kernel.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, the repositories will not disappear in 2012, since the server support remains for 5 years - April 2015.

Support for the desktop disappears in April 2013 - LTS releases are 3 yrs for the desktop and 5 years for the server.  From 12.04 - both the desktop and server support arrangements will be 5 years.

Once the desktop support ends, it doesnt mean the repositories or desktop packages are removed - it will just mean that canonical will not actively update them with stability or security updates.

When the server support ends, it is likely that the repositories will be moved to the old-releases area of ubuntu.com - as described in the [community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades).

Comment: great answer fossfreedom, should i choose answer now, or wait?

Comment: ... thanks ... your choice whether to accept if you are looking for a better answer...